# image moved with 1px above on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

So, I use this Javascript for *hide - show* effect:

```
function effect(id) {
    var h = document.getElementById(id);
    h.style.display = ((h.style.display != 'none') ? 'none' : 'inline');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div">
    <a href="#" onclick="effect('h');"><img src="http://i.imm.io/1jf2j.png"/></a>
    <a href="index.php" class="url" id="h">Home</a>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.div {
    background: #000;
}
.div .url {
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

Here you can test (and edit!) the code: **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dhHiw**
JSFiddle doesn't work for me.

All is good. Except when you click on image. It's moved 1px above. Should I use another image?
Where is the problem? And possible solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically removing the text element. Since the `<div class="div">` does not have a set height, it depends on the elements inside it. When the text is not displayed (`display=none`), the div will resize to only the image.

You can fix this by either setting a height for the div, or by setting `visibility=hidden` for the text instead of `display=none`. When making it hidden, it still has the same dimensions, but it's invisible instead.